# integrating a c# dll in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am forced to integrate a .NET assembly in a ROS node (kinetic).
I have tested the .NET assembly with mono and it works just fine.

What are my chances of creating a succesful ROS node purely in C#?
For example, I would need to subscribe to a topic for receiving image data.
Or would you recommend to wrap the .NET assembly in c++ and use c++ for ROS integration?

I have never done any of the two...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265170/integrating-a-c#-dll-in-ros/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2017-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have decided to wrap the dot net assembly in c++.
After a look at [how to embed mono in a c++ application](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/) it does not look that difficult. I expect the .NET dll to be quite static and the interface to be quite limited.
So there is no need to involve C# in accessing the ROS API, for example worry about how ROS messages are parsed and generated.

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2017-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0